# how to create oauth2 APi for my flask backend

Tags: api, flask, oauth-2.0, zapier

I'm a beginner in Flask, I want to create an oauth2 API to use my backend with external apps, for exemple when another app uses my own app, oauth2 will Intervenes in the process.(enable other apps to use my backend)

to be clear, I want to create an oauth2 API like Google's aouth2 API (used when trying to register in a web site).

Please I need help, thank you.